# Encountered the symbol "set" error oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_Projects is
Cursor C_proj is SELECT PROJECTID FROM PROJECT
ORDER BY PROJECTID;
R_proj C_proj%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN

    OPEN c_proj;
    LOOP
    FETCH c_proj into r_proj;
    EXIT when c_proj%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.Put_line(c_proj.ProjectID);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE c_proj;
    END;

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
EXEC SP_Projects;
```

LINE/COL  ERROR

---

17/1      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SET" 
Errors: check compiler log

Comment: Error starting at line : 18 in command - BEGIN SP_Projects; END; Error report - ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00905: object IS225P.SP_PROJECTS is invalid ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored 06550. 00000 - "line %s, column %s:\n%s" *Cause: Usually a PL/SQL compilation error. *Action: –

Comment: when I put a slash after end; it comes out with this error  ^^

Comment: `DBMS_OUTPUT.Put_line(c_proj.ProjectID);` must be `DBMS_OUTPUT.Put_line(r_proj.ProjectID);`.

Comment: On a side note: I recommend using proper indention to get code more readable. It is hard to see for instance where the loop start and ends.

Answer (score 1):

You need to end procedure with slash `/`:

```
END;
/
```

Comment: For questions which contain just a simple typo, consider voting to close, rather than answering.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I will take care next time. Thanks

Comment: when I put a slash after end; it comes out with this error

Comment: Error starting at line : 18 in command -
BEGIN SP_Projects; END;
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00905: object IS225P.SP_PROJECTS is invalid
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen: I disagree here, because I don't consider this a mere typo. zealous supposes that the OP uses a tool (sqlplus maybe?) that requires the slash and that the OP doesn't know this. On the other hand this answer would have been much better explaining this assumption :-)

Comment: @miapaulina: As the new error says that "SP_PROJECTS is invalid", try `select * from user_errors;` to find out what's wrong. It is probably `c_proj` instead of `r_proj` in `put_line`.

Comment: @zealous . . . Both Thorsten and Tim are correct.  Your answer as it stands is better handled by closing as a typo and leaving a comment.  However, you could explain what the slash is needed for, when and why it is used, perhaps referring to the documentation so the answer actually has some content.